# What is the best way to parse HTML from a Rich Text Editor in Perl?

Tags: html, perl, module, tidy, rich-text-editor

Is there a Perl module out there that can take **bad HTML** (such as what is copied from Microsoft Word) and parse it into **nicely formatted HTML**?  I have looked at **HTML::Tidy**, but it has gotten [horrible reviews on CPAN](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/HTML-Tidy).  We have a custom legacy module that's basically a wrapper for the command line version of tidy (which seems to be pretty much what HTML::Tidy is), but it writes files to disk and reads them back in, which can be a big performance penalty.  Certainly with Perl's awesome text parsing abilities, there's a better way to do this right?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) There really isn't an alternative to [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), since it does the job for most people.  Is there some behavior of the command-line tool that is inadequate for you?  Perhaps if you presented an example of why it's not up to snuff we could get a better understanding of the problem.

2) Regarding performance, you might consider modifying your wrapper to call `open2` on tidy to avoid the disk round-trip:

```
use IPC::Open2;

my $pid = open2(\*FROM_TIDY, \*TO_TIDY, '/usr/bin/tidy')
    or die "couldn't open";

# give tidy our html and close the handle to tell it we're done
print(TO_TIDY $html_string);
close(TO_TIDY);

# read in the tidy html
while (<FROM_TIDY>) {
    print;
}
close(FROM_TIDY);
```

Comment: That's likely to deadlock (with tidy blocking on a write to FROM_TIDY and perl blocking on a write to TO_TIDY).

Comment: Nope.  tidy reads the whole file in before parsing it, then writes the whole file out.